# When trying to locate a list of elements with selenium, the list is empy

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to access to a web element in the web page automationpub.com, I'm trying to locate a element that contains a list of elements that all of them have the element that I want, but I need only the third element on the list. I've already tried css, xpath, className locators to find the list but the list is empty or only have one element but that is not possible.

[Image of the list that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDvqD.png)

I have a class "HomePage" that have a get method for this web element.

```
@FindBy(className="panel-group") 
private List<WebElement> list;

public List<WebElement> getList()
{
    return list;
}
```

And the get method is called in the main class, but when I debug the code to see if I got the 17 elements on the list, I just saw an empty list or a list that have only one element

```
@Test 
public void test(){ 
List<WebElement> x=home.getList();
}
```

The list should have 17 elements, but the actual is none or just one.

Comment: The code snippet you showed has only one element with class=panel-group. Maybe you meant "panel-default"? Also, please do not post text converted to image, keep it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think className="panel-group" will return the parent element. You may locate the child elements using the xpath:
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='panel-group']/div")
This should return the child elements.

There's a way to verify if you are using correct xpath. In developer tools Console, enter your xpath in this format(using the above xpath as example) and press enter:

$x("//div[@class='panel-group']/div")

This will give the list of elements. If the xpath is wrong you will get an empty list.

Comment: That works, thank you, I though that from the parent I could reach de child elements, that was my mistake I didn't try with the one you post. 
Thanks for the tip with the console!!! I didn't know that.